# How to apply `text-overflow` starting with the Nth row of text?

Tags: html, css

[w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

How can I create a div and have the text in it wrap normally but only up to a certain line (e.g. the second line), and from then on have the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property come into effect and hide the remaining text in that div as in the above link?

Comment: Pretty sure this cannot be done with `text-overflow: ellipsis` alone. I have been looking for the same thing for i dont know how long..

Comment: `text-overflow` in multi-line text is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I use the Trunk8 plugin which does exactly what you want. Have a look at the [demo](http://jrvis.com/trunk8/?rel=github)

For example in your case with the plugin you'd use:

```
$('#div').trunk8({
  lines: 2
});
```

[Plugin Link](https://github.com/rviscomi/trunk8)

Comment: I'll certainly give it it a try, it looks promising. Of course, I'd have preferred to rely solely on CSS and HTML.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough Hey, thanks for showing me that! I just happened upon this page and found a new jQuery plugin to add to my toolbox!

Answer (score 2):

For a pure CSS workaround and since `text-overflow` is not intended to multi-line text you may use a *hack* if you have **fixed width and line-height** for your text container and control where your text should start hiding.

CSS for simulating `text-overflow`:

```
div{
    width:55%;
    padding:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    height:20px; /*for showing 2 lines of text*/
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

div:after{
    content:"...";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:10px;
}
```

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kfJAy/

Comment: Argh! If it weren't for the fact that you can't include the suspension points within the same text container (see [http://jsfiddle.net/kfJAy/1/](here)), I would have immediately selected this answer. Nevertheless, many thanks for a brilliant workaround!

Comment: Yes I know there are many limitations to this approach but it may be useful if you are using a *fixed* text. I used it once for a project but I could (and had to) position the *dots* to the pixel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no css for what you want to do, but a possible workaround is this:

```
.ellipsis{
    line-height: 10px; //10px for easy multiplication
    height: 30px; //line-height * n
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be explaining what you mean by "10px for easy mulutiplication?"

Comment: @AndreiOniga you're right it doesn't work - sorry; I thought it would.

Comment: Okay, just seemed like it could confuse people, unintentionally